# No module named pymysql

Tags: python, apache, django-rest-framework, pymysql

Getting a 500 internal error when attempting to create an apache/django server that runs on digital ocean. After checking the log.error i can see the error below

```
import pymysql as db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pymysql
```

Within Terminal...

```
python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
python3-pymysql is already the newest version (0.9.3-2ubuntu3).
```

```
pip3 install PyMySQL
Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.3)
```

Within Python...

```
import pymysql as db

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any IDE? Did you check the interpreter configuration for running your code?

Comment: You need to install the package with `pip3 install pymysql`.

Comment: That simply returns a " Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.3)"

Comment: @Redstain: did you do that when the *virtual environment* was active?

Comment: Followed this tutorial step by step.  https://blearningclub.com/blog/deploy-your-django-project-on-digitalocean/

Comment: You should create a `venv` with `python3 -m venv venv`.  Then `source venv/bin/activate`.  Install your dependencies `pip3 install PyMySQL` and others. When you invoke python3 do it with `/path/to/venv/bin/python` .  Also, I'd recommend nginx with uwsgi over apache.

Answer (score 2):

use `python -m pip install pymysql`

that used the pip for the Python interpreter you specified as `python`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.3)

Comment: in a python interpreter run these commands to see where its looking for packages `import sys` + `print(sys.path)`

Comment: This was key; all other install commands seemed to work fine, but running the code always resulted in “No module named 'pymysql' found." This worked. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo systemctl stop gunicorn

source env/bin/activate

python -m pip install pymysql

deactivate

sudo systemctl start gunicorn
```

works for me.